# Interval not causing re-render in react component

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks

I am using the useEffect react hook to set an interval for a countdown variable. I have noticed that when the tab in my browser isn't active, the internal stops working. If the tab is active the code works exactly as expected.

Is there a better way to do this? Below is an example of the code.

```
export default function CountdownTimer({ minutes_left, action }) { 

const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState();

function updateTimer() {
    const remaining = ...work out time left
    setTimeLeft(remaining);
  }

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      updateTimer();
      if (timeLeft.asMilliseconds() <= 0) {
        action();
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

return (
    <p>{timeLeft}</p>
  );
}
```

I have implemented solutions in Dan Abramov's post [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) about this problem. However Dan's solution's also don't render when the tab is inactive.

Comment: intervals in general are a rather poor tool for handling countdowns if you need them to be precise down to the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is how browsers work: inactive tabs are deprioritised and timers get heavily throttled. Remember that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are most expressly *not* "run code once X ms have passed", they are "run code after *at least* X ms have passed" without any guarantee that things won't actually happen much, much later due to scheduling (e.g. whether the tab is active, or even visible as far as the OS can inform the browser) or even just because a bit of JS code took longer than your indicated interval to complete and so your timeout literally can't fire until it's done (because JS is single-threaded).

For Firefox, See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#Policies_in_place_to_aid_background_page_performance on what kind of throttling is performed on timers, and for Chrome, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

(For any other browser, a web search should find you similar documentation.)

However, think about what it means for a tab to become a background process: if your users can't see your tab, why would you need to update anything at all? Your users won't be able to see those updates. Instead, consider suspending purely visual tasks when a tab becomes invisible, and then resuming them when the tab becomes visible again, and using a clock-time check to determine whether "things need to happen".

In fact, this is important to do even on a foreground tab if you use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`: 10 consecutive `setTimeout(..., 100)` do *not* imply that it'll be exactly 1 second later once they're done, it means it's *at least* 1s later when we're done but we could easily reach that "one second later" mark by the time the 7th or 8th timeout fires because JS is single threaded, and if some task took a while, your timeout won't fire until that task is done. So you're going to at the very least need to update your code for that already anyway.

Comment: What would you suggest in lieu of using setInterval and setTimeout?

Comment: "not updating". Mark a "start time" in some accessible variable/const, and then capture your `setInterval` for calling the function that compares the current time to that start time. If the difference exceeds your threshold value, trigger what needs to happen and clear your interval. But if the user blurs the page, _clear your setInterval and "do nothing"_ because the user's not looking at yout page. When the page regains focus, reschedule your setInterval and also immediately trigger your check function. It's entirely likely the threshold's been passed, which will get handled correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because useEffect call use clearInterval function after the first render. Here's how the cleanup for `useEffect` works with the returned function - [Example Using Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

Comment: Mm actually.. I have found this has help, however it still becomes not in sync, often now only by a few seconds.

Comment: I have updated the description with a comment about trying the solutions from that blog post. They also encounter this problem. I am thinking possibly to do a request every 30 seconds or so to re-sync the timer.